# Gitlab send current date in output

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab-ci.yml file. After each step, I'd like to send an output via REST containing the current date. Just sending an output via REST works but I have difficulties passing in the currentdate. I'm currently solving it like below (by exporting a variable)

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

before_script:
  - apk add curl
  - export mydate = $(date -I)

stages:
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate
    - <curl request>
  variables:
    msg: "$mydate => Validation complete, moving on"


plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out "planfile"
  variables:
    msg: "$mydate => Planning complete, moving on"
  dependencies:
    - validate
```

> $ export mydate = $(date -I) /bin/sh: export: line 97: : bad variable name

Whatever variable name I choose, I always get this error message

Comment: Use the same syntax you used in `entrypoint`: `'mydate = $(date -I)'`. no `export`

Comment: Tried this. Fixes the error but I still don't see a date in the output

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a space in your variable name.
Instead of writing `export mydate = $(date -I)`, write `export mydate=$(date -I)`.

Comment: Tried this. Fixes the error but I still don't see a date in the output

Comment: You seem to be in the `hashicorp/terraform:light` image in the `before_script`. `hashicorp/terraform:light` doesn't have OS commands such as `date`. Try using a different image and installing Terraform and cURL in that.